# Translate C code into Haskell

Tags: c, haskell, translate

How do I translate this portion of C code into Haskell? From what I know, I must use the State monad, but I don't know how.

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
x =  x * y;
y = y + x;
```

Comment: I just want to modify the value of the variables.

Comment: It would help if you had more context. Why do you want to reassign x and y? In your code, you don't need to do it at all, so... it's hard to translate it when one could argue the translation is simply `x = 2; y = 4`

Comment: If you want to use a language that allows reassignment of variables, maybe Haskell isn't a good choice. If you want to learn to program in Haskell in a Haskellish way, then maybe you should reconsider how you design your code to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: That's just an example. I can't post the code here. I must implement sth. to simulate the behavior of a setter/getter.

Comment: @Bigba Why can't you? It may be useful to have at least a minimal example that explains why you need this functionality. If this is homework, please add the tag [homework].

Comment: Straight translation isn't always the best choice, since Haskell and C come from very different paradigms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A literal translation would use [IORefs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-IORef.html):

```
import Data.IORef

main :: IO ()
main = do x <- newIORef 1
          y <- newIORef 2
          y_val <- readIORef y
          modifyIORef x (\v -> v * y_val)
          x_val <- readIORef x
          modifyIORef y (\v -> v + x_val)
```

As you can see, imperative programming is ugly in Haskell. This is intentional, to coax you into using functional style. You can define some helper functions, though, to make this more bearable:

```
import Data.IORef

-- x := f x y
combineToR :: (a -> t -> a) -> IORef a -> IORef t -> IO ()
combineToR f x y = do y_val <- readIORef y
                      modifyIORef x (\v -> f v y_val)

addTo :: Num a => IORef a -> IORef a -> IO ()
addTo = combineToR (+)

multWith :: Num a => IORef a -> IORef a -> IO ()
multWith = combineToR (*)

main :: IO ()
main = do x <- newIORef 1
          y <- newIORef 2
          multWith x y
          addTo y x
```

Answer (score 9):

Let's assume, you have that pair of integers as state:

```
f = do put (1,2)
       modify (\(x,y) -> (x*y,y))
       modify (\(x,y) -> (x,y+x))
```

Is that, what you want?

Comment: First result on Google on the query "set and get in haskell" takes me to http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/State_Monad. I guess the translated code would look like one of the concrete examples given there.

Comment: note that this is slightly different from the C version in that in the C code x is modified *before* y is set, not simultaneously, so you'd probably need `put (1,2) >>= modify (\(x,y) -> (x*y,y)) >>= modify (\(x,y) -> (x,y+x))`

Answer (score 6):

The point of functional languages for you to not do that, make a new value, or use recursion.

If you like to just print these values,

```
x = 1
y = 2
a = x*y
b = y+x

main = do
           putStrLn ("x*y: " ++ a)
           putStrLn ("y+x: " ++ b)
```

If this is a homework assignment, please mark it as so, and I will change my answer.

Comment: It is indeed a homework assignment. A part of it, to be more precise. I must translate in Haskell a phone book implemented in C. I just wanted to see how do I do the set/get operations.

Comment: @Bigba Mbum You probably don't need them. In Haskell, there are only seldom uses of set and get operations. Most of that can be defined in pure ways.

Comment: get and set is a very imperative thing, I would not use it unless your teacher knows where you live and drinks an excessive amount of vodka and watches horror films.

Answer (score 2):

another way is to think about "versions" of the variable - the x at the start is different than the x at the end. For example, in C say you have a variable that sometimes stores a number in fahrenheit and then you convert it to centigrade, like this:

```
  temp = 40;
  temp = convertFtoC(temp);
```

then you could think about these as two different variables:

```
   tempF = 40;
   tempC=  convertFtoC(tempF);
```

Without knowing what your x and y are to invent better names for them, you might end up writing in haskell:

```
xa = 1;
ya = 2;
xb =  xa * ya;
yb = ya + xb;
```

In some cases, that can be a nice way to think about how to make your code more functional and less imperative.

Answer (score 1):

If you identify your "mutable" variables with a tuple, you can define transformation operations on it and "chain" it together:

```
vars x y = (x,y)
setX (x,y) x' = (x', y) 
setY (x,y) y' = (x, y') 
appX (x,y) f = (f x, y)
appY (x,y) f = (x, f y)
app2X (x, y) f = (f x y, y)
app2Y (x, y) f = (x, f x y)
```

`set...` sets a value, `app...` applies a function on it,  `app2...` applies a function on both values and stores it in x or y. Then you can do something like:

```
(vars 3 5) `setX` 14 `appY` (2*)
-- result: (14,10)
```

Your example would become:

```
(vars 1 2) `app2X` (*) `app2Y` (+)  
-- result: (2,4)
```

Of course this stretches the definition of "mutable" a bit, but this solution is already half way to the `State` or `Writer` monad.